# Transfer data between db on windows to linux

Tags: linux, windows, db2

I had this error, when i trying transfer data from db2 db on windows to db on linux, by ibm data studio:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD( 'LOAD FROM Path\file.dat OF IXF  REPLACE INTO 
Schema.Table(ID, SID, REFERENCE, UCI, STATE, DEBTORNAME, DEBTORADDR,DEBTORZIP, DEBTORCITY, DEBTORPROVINCE, DEBTORCOUNTRY, DEBTORIBAN,
DEBTORBIC,CREDITORNAME, CREDITORADDR, CREDITORZIP, CREDITORCITY, CREDITORPROVINCE,CREDITORCOUNTRY, CREDITORIBAN, CREDITORBIC, ORGANIZATIONID,
SEQUENCETYPE, ROLE,LASTDATEOFCOLL, LASTTYPEOFCOLL, CURRENTSCHEME, SIGNATURECITY, SIGNATUREDATE, REFDEBTNAME, REFCREDNAME, COMMENTS, SOURCE,
LASTMODIFIEDBY, LASTMODIFIED, LASTSTATE, MAXAMOUNT, REQUESTCOUNT, MAXREQUESTS, VALIDFROM, VALIDTO, MANDATETYPE, HASAMENDMENT, PREVIOUSMANDATEID,
ORIREFERENCE, ORIUCI, ORICREDITORNAME, ORIDEBTORIBAN, ORIDEBTORBIC, EXTERNALID, EXTERNALREFERENCE, CUSTSPEC1, CUSTSPEC2, CUSTSPEC3, CREATIONTIME)'
 )
```

And I had this error:

```
An unexpected token "COMMENTS" was found following ",".  Expected tokens may include:  "<identifier>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.19.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COMMENTS` is apparently a reserved word (although when I look up the DB2 reserved word list, it only contains `COMMENT`, not the plural form). So you need to put it in quotes to escape it.

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD( 'LOAD FROM Path\file.dat OF IXF  REPLACE INTO 
Schema.Table(ID, SID, REFERENCE, UCI, STATE, DEBTORNAME, DEBTORADDR,DEBTORZIP, DEBTORCITY, DEBTORPROVINCE, DEBTORCOUNTRY, DEBTORIBAN,
DEBTORBIC,CREDITORNAME, CREDITORADDR, CREDITORZIP, CREDITORCITY, CREDITORPROVINCE,CREDITORCOUNTRY, CREDITORIBAN, CREDITORBIC, ORGANIZATIONID,
SEQUENCETYPE, ROLE,LASTDATEOFCOLL, LASTTYPEOFCOLL, CURRENTSCHEME, SIGNATURECITY, SIGNATUREDATE, REFDEBTNAME, REFCREDNAME, ''COMMENTS'', SOURCE,
LASTMODIFIEDBY, LASTMODIFIED, LASTSTATE, MAXAMOUNT, REQUESTCOUNT, MAXREQUESTS, VALIDFROM, VALIDTO, MANDATETYPE, HASAMENDMENT, PREVIOUSMANDATEID,
ORIREFERENCE, ORIUCI, ORICREDITORNAME, ORIDEBTORIBAN, ORIDEBTORBIC, EXTERNALID, EXTERNALREFERENCE, CUSTSPEC1, CUSTSPEC2, CUSTSPEC3, CREATIONTIME)'
 )
```

Comment: To ensure a correct result, do not use the doublequote character, instead use two adjacent single-quote characters on either side of the COMMENTS token.  Usage of the single doublequote character inside the argument to admin_cmd can result in SQL0206.

Comment: @mao I'm not a DB2 programmer, but I read it [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_reservedwords.html): **if the quotation mark (") is the escape character that begins and ends delimited identifiers, "ALL" can appear as a column name in a SELECT statement.**

Comment: Won't two adjacent single quotes just turn into single quotes, resulting in a literal string in the argument query, not an escaped identifier?

Comment: Just try it at the CLP and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @mao I don't have a DB2 database to try it with, so I'll take your word and I've edited my answer.